# 0xc51bad03 crash on watchOS3.1

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, apple-watch, crash-reports, watchos-3

My watch app uses background refresh tasks heavily, and work during task is asynchronous. Sometimes (once in 15-20 background task executions) it gets terminated by OS with 0xc51bad03 reason.
Release [notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/RN-watchOSSDK-3.1/) of watchOS3.1 say:

> Background Refresh
>   Violations of system resources will result in a crash report for your application. The exception code provides context about the nature of the violation:
>
> - 0xc51bad01 The app used too much CPU time.
> - 0xc51bad02 The app took too much wall time.
> - 0xc51bad03 The app may not have had sufficient runtime to complete the task.

What does this "may not have had sufficient runtime" mean? What can be possible reason? This code have not been explained during WWDC sessions. Looks like this crash does not depend on exact place in my code that is executed at the moment.

Crash report except does not make reason clearer:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0xc51bad03
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x264216d0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2642149c mach_msg + 40
2   CoreFoundation                  0x267aed88 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 154
3   CoreFoundation                  0x267ad04c __CFRunLoopRun + 1068
4   CoreFoundation                  0x26701f74 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 354
5   Foundation                      0x2704307c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 246
6   Foundation                      0x2708ff5a -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 80
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x265330de _xpc_objc_main + 600
8   libxpc.dylib                    0x265346fe xpc_main + 166
9   Foundation                      0x27217fea service_connection_handler + 0
10  PlugInKit                       0x303eb1be -[PKService run] + 774
11  WatchKit                        0x342efe00 main + 134
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x26344566 start + 2

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest attach the crash log along with your app to https://bugreport.apple.com

Your question to release note is probably answered the best by engineers at Apple.